# How to create an sql table in pymysql correctly?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, pymysql

```
import pymysql.cursors

from config import host, user, password, db_name

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        port=3306,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    try:

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE 'user'(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(32), password varchar(32), PRIMARY KEY(id);)"
            cursor.execute(create_table_query)
            print("Create")
    finally:
        connection.close()
    print("Success//")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Connecting//")
    print(ex)
```

Please help!
Terminal:
Connecting//
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user'(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(32), password varchar(32), PRIMARY KE' at line 1")

Process finished with exit code 0

Process finished with exit code 0
Error:(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user'(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(32), password varchar(32), PRIMARY KE' at line 1")

Comment: The error message seems to cut off after `PRIMARY KE`.  Are you sure this is your real SQL?

Comment: This is python with the pymysql library

Comment: That isn't what I asked.  Are you sure that the SQL statement that you posted here in the question is exactly the same SQL statement in your code?  The error message seems to suggest that your actual SQL statement stops after `PRIMARY KE`.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE 'user'(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(32), password varchar(32), PRIMARY KEY(id));` semicolon in the wrong place

Comment: It seems that the operator is the same, if I understand correctly what you are talking about.

Comment: `'` is the delimiter for *text*, not objects. Use `CREATE TABLE user (...` or `CREATE TABLE "user"...`. Try the SQL query in eg pgAdmin first to ensure it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we check your SQL query separatly, it will be as this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'user'
(
   id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   name varchar(32), 
   password varchar(32), 
   PRIMARY KEY(id);
)
```

As you can see, you have semicolon inside the structure of the table instead of end of the whole operator.
Please, try this variant:

```
CREATE TABLE 'user'(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(32), password varchar(32), PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Which we can transfer to the better view:

```
CREATE TABLE 'user'
(
   id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   name varchar(32), 
   password varchar(32), 
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: Does not work. Returns the same error.

Comment: Try removing single quotes https://dbfiddle.uk/TD84i8lN

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much)